# Firebase in android not removing nodes

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have this item in the database

[image]

And I have a method for removing items, but is not working, this is the method

```
public void deleteBag(String bagUid, final FirebaseDeleteBaglListener listener) {
    Query query = dbReference.child(FirebaseChild.bags.name()).child(bagUid);
    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
            listener.notifyBagDeleted();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

It gets the reference well, but the method `setValue(null)` is doing nothing (I've also tried the `removeValues()`.

I don't get any exception or some kind of response, I hope you can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the path is right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I beleive you have a model class that inserts your items into the database.
so what you have to do is to use that class to reference the object directly and perform the required action on it. Something like this.

```
public void deleteBag(String bagUid, final FirebaseDeleteBaglListener listener) {
Query query = dbReference.child(FirebaseChild.bags.name()).child(bagUid);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
 //This shouldn't be there
  //dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);
//instead use the modelclass you used inserting data, to reference the object 
      Modelclass mode =  dataSnapshot.getValue(Modelclass.class);
  /** Note this line indicates the getter and setter method for the particular object that is being referenced**/     
     mode.setItem(null)
     listener.notifyBagDeleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

}

Comment: **Note** But if you want to delete the entire content on the node then you simply use a `datasnapshot.setValue(null);` instead of `dataSnapshot.getRef().setValue(null);` on the sixth line of your code

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a query against the Firebase Database, there will potentially be multiple results. You're using a `ValueEventListener`, so the snapshot contains a list of all results. Even if there is only a single result, the snapshot will contain a list of one result.

You need to loop over `DataSnapshot.getChildren()` to get the individual items matching your query:

```
public void deleteBag(String bagUid, final FirebaseDeleteBaglListener listener) {
  Query query = dbReference.child(FirebaseChild.bags.name()).child(bagUid);
  query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        child.getRef().removeValue();
      }
      listener.notifyBagDeleted();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
  });
}
```